# LINQ Select First

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Hi I have this bit of linq code

```
var fp = lnq.attaches.First(a => a.sysid == sysid).name;
```

When profiled it generates the following t-sql

```
SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[sysid], [t0].[name], [t0].[att_size], [t0].[cid], [t0].[flags], [t0].[contents] 
FROM [lntmuser].[attach] AS [t0]
```

The way I look at it, it is returning like a select *, which will cause the query to perform a table scan rather then use an index.  Bad for performance.

How could I select just the name column, like:

```
SELECT TOP (1)[t0].[name] FROM [lntmuser].[attach] AS [t0]
```

Thanks in advance

---

Edit:
Broken Glasses Solution profiles as desired

```
SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[name]
FROM [lntmuser].[attach] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[sysid] = @p0
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Project to the `name` property before using `First()`:

```
var fp = lnq.attaches.Where(a => a.sysid == sysid)
                     .Select(a => a.name)
                     .First();
```

This doesn't change the use of an index though - for that your `Where` clause is responsible (in your initial query the lambda you passed to `First()`). Both queries benefit from an index on the `name` column, the second one is just faster because only one column value has to be materialized.

Comment: Would be curious to see what this code looks like in Profiler.

Comment: @dtown123 Yeah that was the first thing I did lol, I added the code in the answer.

Comment: It would be a little more compact (and possibly performant) to say `lnq.attaches.First( a => a.sysid == sysid ).name`

Comment: @EthanBrown: No - that was what this question was all about. Read the question ;-) - `First()` without prior projection will materialize **all** columns in this case - OP wanted just to materialize one column value