# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1 [Manager.Data.Channel]' to type 'Manager.Data.Channel'

Tags: c#, linq, exception, ado.net

In a Win7 app, I am trying to update several fields in an ADO.NET database table called "Channel", with an EntitySetMapping Name of "Channels", using EntityClient in the EF to access SqlServerCe 3.5 (IPManager_DBEntities).

With the VS 2010 IDE, the code compiles fine and Intellisense has no complaints.  The format of the Channel datatable is referenced at the bottom as the various fields in a row (selected by Channel "Number") need to be updated with information passed to it from code which is not shown for the sake of simplicity.  Nothing I have Googled during the past several days has solved my Type Casting dilemma. Using LINQ, I get this RunTime Exception:

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1 [Manager.Data.Channel]' to type 'Manager.Data.Channel'".

```
    // Update channel status with information parsed from the data packet.
    using (IPManager_DBEntities context = new IPManager_DBEntities())
    {
        Channel thisChannelRow = (Channel)(from CE
                                             in context.Channels
                                          where CE. Number == int.Parse(IDLine[2])
                                         select CE);

        // Throwing exception after setting up this query:
        //   "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1
        //   [Manager.Data.Channel]' to type 'Manager.Data.Channel'"
        //  During debug sessions, "thisChannelRow" is null as a result.

        MessageBox.Show("thisChannelRow. Channel = " + thisChannelRow.Number );

            ThisChannel.StatusID = int.Parse(IDLine[5]);
            ThisChannel.Cycle = int.Parse(IDLine[4]);
            ThisChannel.Modified = DateTime.Now;
            context.SaveChanges();
     }
```

I hope someone has a solution to help me through this predicament.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LINQ query is returning an object of a type descendant from `IEnumerable<T>`, not `Channel`, even if there is just one item in the sequence. To get the actual item, use [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx):

```
Channel thisChannelRow = (Channel)(from CE
                                   in context.Channels
                                   where CE. Number == int.Parse(IDLine[2])
                                   select CE).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx), [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx), or [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) if any of those are a better fit.

Comment: FirstOrDefault() or SingleOrDefault() both worked well.  Thanks for your quick response.  Can you briefly explain how using either of these extensions resolves the Type Mismatch issue?

Comment: Sure. So, before you call `FirstOrDefault`, the object that you have is an `IEnumerable<Channel>` (or something like that), because all LINQ queries return collections that derive from `IEnumerable<T>`. When you call, `FirstOrDefault`, it returns the first *element* from within the collection. Thus, you can cast it without error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your first command is returning an `IEnumerable` which isn't the same type as the objects it enumerates.

Try adding `.First()` to the end of your LINQ ala [LINQ Select First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149982/linq-select-first)

This is needed because your original LINQ statement returns a type of `IEnumerable<Channel>` which is not the same as a `Channel` and therefore you're getting a type mis-match. You can think of your initial LINQ statement as returning a list of things, but you're trying to put that list into a single item. The `.First()` at the end tells the computer to just grab the first element from that list and only return that. Therefore, with the updated LINQ statement you are now storing a `Channel` in a `Channel` and so no more type mis-match.

Comment: Thanks for your swift response.  The .First() extension works as well as the suggestion from @FishBasketGordo to try FirstOrDefault() or SingleOrDefault(), which also worked fine.  You guys saved my day!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I could fix it by using the AddRange methode.

```
 Public Function GetMessages(ByVal Issue As Issue) As List(Of Message)
        Dim Res As New List(Of Message)
        If Issue IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim db As New ProjectManagerEntities
            Res.AddRange(From item As Message In db.Messages
                                       Where item.IssueSet_Id = Issue.Id _
                                       Select item)

        End If

        Return Res
    End Function
```